# VB6 Will not Create EXE file - But it use to?

Tags: file, vb6, exe

I am trying to compile a VB6 project.  On the File Menu it use to display MAKE PROJ1.EXE. Now it displays MAKE PROJ1. (note EXE is missing)  The program runs fine in the IDE.  I can start with full compile.  I can even create a set up disk from the packaging and deployment wizard.  I have a sucessful install, but the package will not run.  There is no exe file.  Other vb project compile just fine.  Can anyone lend a hand????

Comment: When you choose File | Make PROJ1, what appears in the **Make Project** dialog box?  You should be able to set the filename (including .exe) there...

Comment: This may sound trivial but aren't you asked to specify an exe name (when you press Alt-F, K to select the Make command from the File menu)? If you specify a file name there (like 'proj.exe') this file is not created? If so, it means that your code no longer compiles.

Answer (score 1):

That's weird

Open up the .VBP project file using Notepad and verify the following entry is correct

```
ExeName32="PROJ1.EXE"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Right-click on VB6 toolbar
2. Customize
3. Make some change
4. Reset
5. Close
6. Make ... .exe

After that, it should work.